# How to increase fbx size while applying Quaternion in ThreeJs

Tags: three.js, quaternions

I'm trying to load an object using fbx loader and apply quaternion to rotate in an orbit. Rotation is working but object looks far away on the screen.

Here is the code that i'm trying.

```
fbxLoader.load('models/fbx/yarn_with_mtl.fbx', function (yarn) {
    yarn.traverse(function(child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            child.receiveShadow = true;
            child.castShadow = true;
        }
    });
    yarn.name = "yarn";
    yarn.position.set(0, 0, 688);// this increases to right size
    yarnModal = yarn;
    scene.add(yarn);
});


quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(axis, 0.005);
if(yarnModal)yarnModal.position.applyQuaternion(quaternion); //This is reseting the object size back to small
```

Comment: Did you specify a camera?

Comment: Yes. I did specify a camera. I could able to make it bigger by setting Z-position( yarn.position.set(0, 0, 688); ). But when I apply quaternion, it is going back to small.

Comment: It's probably that the `yarn.position.set(0, 0, 688);` will be overwritten when you apply the quaternion. You might check the coordinates of the camera-z itself.